# Why does htaccess bug but everything works after putting everything into a new folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I got a website and set up some htaccess stuff like errordocuments and clean url rewrites.
The problem I'm currently encountering is that the rewrite doesn't always work and end on my 404 error page.

- This link works: `example.com/texts/2`
- This link works too: `example.com/texts/3`
- But this doesn't: `example.com/texts/1`
- This doesn't work aswell: `example.com/texts/4`

although it did work yesterday.

I edited some stuff but because it wasn't working, I reset it to the backup I did before editing so the `.htaccess` is exactly the same.

The funny thing tho is that if I put everything in a new folder `/test/` i.E.
it works just fine.

Now I don't want to always change the folder and links between the different sites after I edited something in the `.htaccess` so I would like to know why this problem occurs and how to prevent and fix it.

I did search for like a few hours now and didn't find anything that comes close to my error.

My `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=403

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^texts/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=texts&id=$1
RewriteRule ^texts/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=texts&id=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your error log? Did you try to create a mod_rewrite log to see what happens exactly? Also, do you have another redirection set up elsewhere, in the Apache configuration file for example or in a previous directory?

Comment: the only error I see is "Undefined offset: 4" then follows the file directory and referrer.
I don't have any other redirections setup, I kept everything in the htaccess excluding the https redirect but that doesn't apply because it already is https.
And as far as I know undefined offset is some array error.

Comment: What I don't understand is that you should be seeing 404 for all these, since anything that triggers any of the first rules will also trigger the last one. Did you try to add [L] to each of your rules?

Comment: [L] to every rule? Like RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
If so it doesn't change anything :)

Comment: @Technoh None of those would trigger a 404 since the request is rewritten to `index.php` first. But yes, they should have the `L` flag to prevent further (unnecessary) processing. It's likely a caching issue from a previous incarnation of these directvies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser has cached the 404 redirect rule for those paths that do not work.

Try emptying the cache of the browser and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=403
>
> :
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404 [L,R=301]
> ```

It's already been identified as a caching issue. But you shouldn't have been getting a caching issue in the first place if it wasn't for how you are triggering your 404... you are 301 (permanent) redirecting this to `/404` (a virtual URL) that is then further rewritten. This is bad. 301s will be persistently cached by the browser, but you also lose all the information about the URL that triggered the 404 in the first place.

Why not configure your 404 in the same way you have configured your 403? ie.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404
```

Which is what a request to `/404` would seem to do. However, now you can examine elements of the request to analyse the 404.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
> RewriteRule ^texts/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=texts&id=$1
> RewriteRule ^texts/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=texts&id=$1
> ```

Apart from mixing `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` (they refer to the same thing in this context), `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. It looks like they should apply to the first two rules (at least).

However, those two rules can be combined into one anyway, since you are simply making the trailing slash optional. BUT, if you make the trailing slash optional on an internal rewrite then you are potentially creating "duplicate content". Presumably only one URL is canonical (at least it should be), ie. you are consistently linking to URLs with or without the trailing slash and not both. So, you should only rewrite one of them. If you want to handle both URLs (with and without a trailing slash) then you should externally "redirect" from one to the other.

For example, favouring URLs without a trailing slash (as in your examples) and redirecting URLs that end in a trailing slash:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404

# Canonical redirect to remove trailing slash from all URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^texts/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=texts&id=$1
```

I also removed the filesystem check for a file, since it's highly unlikely that a request that matches the regex `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` will map to a real file. Filesystem checks are relatively expensive, so if you don't need them; don't use them.

Comment: Thanks for the long, clear and very very helpful explanation! I didn't use the ErrorDocument 404 too because it didn't seem to really work. But your htaccess works great! :) Thanks a lot